# Annual data to monthly data by averaging annual data and creating new rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have an annual data set (in datafame) which I want to convert to a monthly data. A sample of the annual data is below:

```
ID  Date    Fee
A   1/1/2001    1
B   1/1/2001    
C   1/1/2001    3
```

I want to convert it to a quarterly dataframe by averaging the Fee column and creating extra columns for other quarters, such as:

```
ID  Date    Fee
A   1/1/2001    0.25
A   3/1/2001    0.25
A   6/1/2001    0.25
A   9/1/2001    0.25
B   1/1/2001    
B   3/1/2001    
B   6/1/2001    
B   9/1/2001    
C   1/1/2001    0.75
C   3/1/2001    0.75
C   6/1/2001    0.75
C   9/1/2001    0.75
```

Sorry I don't sample codes that I have been working on, because I don't really know where to start. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: How is this data stored? Pandas dataframe? Lists/arrays? text file(s)?

Comment: It's in Pandas dataframe

Comment: Then you want [pandas resample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling) for resampling time series into different increments

Comment: This is the way to go. Thanks.